# Why does Wordpress search returns same number of results for every search query?

Tags: posts, wp-query, search

I am hitting a brick wall, I am searching something on a site I am building and on every search it returns 10 results when I know in the index in relevanssi it shows more for the term I am searching on.

Does anyone know what the issue is with it?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: what does your template code look like? do you have pagination links? the query is probably paginated, showing 10 posts per page.

Comment: What about the `wp-admin`'s `Settings` > `Reading` setting about Displaying posts per page? I think that is set to 10 posts. And without a pagination link you can't understand that there are more results there. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's pagination problem.

WordPress paginates all queries by default. And default value for `posts_per_page` is 10, I guess.

So if you don't override this parameter and you don't show pagination on your page, then you'll see only 10 results (first page of results).

Is it your own query? If so, add `'posts_per_page' => -1` to it.

If not, add pagination to search results page (or change number of posts per page in settings).

Comment: ah haaaaaaa! You know what, when your so deep in development and difficult functionality you forget about the most simplest of site settings. Thanks!

Comment: @Mdunbavan Been there, done that ;)